# Excel .CSV File UTF -8 Encoding not working

Tags: excel, utf-8, character-encoding, formatting

I've got an application that exports a .CSV file with many data, however every time where there is an accent, the files changes the letter to $#231;,

Already converted the file and the text to UTF-8 and it does not fix the problem

Tried the conversion with Excel and also Open Office without success.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this issue ?

Follow an example of wrong data extracted (the text is in Brazilian language):

Lol, after i paste the wrong data in the StackOverflow text to post, the data convert to the correct data.

Anybody has any idea ?

[Data Conversion Correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRPBC.png)

Comment: What are you using Excel for in this situation? Surely there are programs that understand the encoding.

Comment: Im using Excel 2015 in Mac. Not sure if this is a mac issue or something else.

Comment: When you receive any text file you have know/ask/listen for which character encoding it uses. Then you can tell that to the programs that you open it with. For Excel that would be what its text import wizard calls the "file origin". If you are getting the file via HTTP, listen to the Content-Type response header.